# How Select n separate list<int> with overlap from one list<int> in functional way in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq, functional-programming, reactive-programming

In C# I have a list like this:

```
var sequence = new List<int> { 10, 7, 10, 1, 10, 5, 10, 8 , 11 , 50 };
```

I want to create 10 separate list by iterating through the sequence and in each iteration select three element instead of one element.

[image: Iterating though list with overlap]

I wrote code below for this purpose but it has flaws and must be a better way of doing that:

```
var sequence = new List<int> { 10, 7, 10, 1, 10, 5, 10, 8 , 11 , 50 };
var lists = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
        .Select(i =>
        {
            var list = sequence.GetRange(i, 3);
            return list;
        }).ToList();
```

P.S.: ‌Functional way I mean somthing like this:

```
var lists = Sequence.Window(sourceSafed.Skip(1)).....Select(window => window.Take(3))......ToList();
```

Comment: What flaws is has? How's the outcome different than the expected outcome?

Comment: Your diagram only has 8 output lists, not 10. How do you expect to get 10 output lists?

Comment: I corrected the diagram. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments already stated there is nothing really wrong with your code. To make it look more LINQish you could write:

```
var sequence = new List<int> { 10, 7, 10, 1, 10, 5, 10, 8 , 11 , 50 };
var lists = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
    .Select(i => sequence.Skip(i).Take(3))
    // If for further usage it makes sense to materialize each subset
    //.Select(i => sequence.Skip(i).Take(3).ToList())
    .ToList();
```